# MySQL: Country based product list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of products. I want to show the visitor products based on their country (IP location). The table looks like this:

```
Product ID, Name, Price, Size, Color, ...
```

This table is "read-heavy", I seldom write new entries to it.

I thought of this solution: Add to the table every country as a column. There I can set true or false depending if I want to show a certain product to visitors from a certain country.

```
Product ID, Name, Price, Size, Color, ...,  USA, France, Spain, China
```

There are about 200 countries so the table will have many columns. The script gets an incredible amount of request. The query will be called +1million per minute. So I need some solution with good performance. But I don't think this solution is good. The most important factor is performance.

I am using PHP, MySQL.

Comment: *"The query will be called +1million per minute."* - Sounds like a big contract.

Comment: It is a big contract. And you are incredible fast reader. I just clicked on submit and you answered.

Comment: Incredibly fast reader and typist.

Comment: I'd normalize by creating a Country table and then a country-to-product relation table. Records will only show in the relation table if product is available in the country.

Comment: sounds like the table is read-heavy and written to seldomly (in comparison), I would construct your relational tables the _correct_ way and depend on result caching, as opposed to straight-up brute-force query optimization.

Comment: In addition to what others are saying here make sure that your tables are properly indexed.

Answer (score 1):

That will be a nightmare to maintain. As countries come and go you will have to modify your model accordingly. I would suggest something like:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_COUNTRY -- perhaps there''s a better name for this
( PRODUCT_ID ... 
, COUNTRY_CODE CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,    CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCT_COUNTRY PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID, COUNTRY_CODE)
,    CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCT FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES PRODUCTS (PRODUCT_ID)
,    CONSTRAINT FK_COUNTRY FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRY_CODE) REFERENCES COUNTRIES (COUNTRY_CODE)
) ENGINE = INNODB
```

Comment: `CHAR(3)` should probably need to be increased ever so slightly. Just a thought.

Comment: Agreeing with @Fred-ii-

Comment: Why, ISO 3166-3 codes consists of three chars? Do you have some other standard in mind?

Comment: Why use INNODB when MyISAM might be faster? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/which-is-faster-innodb-or-myisam

Comment: (potentially) 3 letters, each taking a byte, plus SQL adds another I do believe. `5` is a safe bet and doesn't "cost" much more ;-)

Comment: If you want constraints and ACID you dont have much of a choice. Beside, I'm not convinced that MyISAM really is faster

Comment: @Fred -ii-, AFAIK DB2 is the only DBMS that specifies the number of bytes, all others specify the number of characters. Therefore 3 is sufficient (2 will probably do), adding more just because would only make the domain muddy.

Comment: @Lennart No problemo. ;-)

Comment: @Lennart there was ISO 3166 - Alpha-4 code. But that is not existing now. :-)

Comment: Thanks! But is this the best solution if my biggest (only) concern is performance?